# Run Time Error 5: Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Tags: excel, vba, variables, runtime-error

I am getting the

> Run Time Error 5: Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

on this line:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=User_File_Path, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```

I have a message box right before that line that tells me the User_File_Path, which is populating, and when I hover over the Connection:=User_File_Path it does display the file path as well... not sure how to fix this. Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
With ActiveSheet
      Dim someTable As QueryTable
      Set someTable = .QueryTables.Add(Connection:=User_File_Path, _
                                          Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
End With
```

Here is the MSDN article for the `QueryTables.Add()` method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/querytables-add-method-excel

This works, if your connection is to a local csv file:

```
Public Sub TestMe()   

    Dim someTable As QueryTable
    Set someTable = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
                    "TEXT;C:\MyText.csv", _
                    Destination:=Range("$A$1"))

    someTable.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Vityata- unfortunately, no luck. When I lay it out like that it highlights the QueryTable line red.

Comment: Hi Vityata- I figured it out by recording a manual version. I was missing this: "Text;" & User_File_Path & User_File_Name ... otherwise, my formatting works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

`"Text;" & User_File_Path & User_File_Name`

i.e.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="Text;" & User_File_Path & User_File_Name, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```